# Compiling qwt for arm

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, cross-compiling

For a project I want to/have to crosscompile qwt for arm. Thus I wanted to use the QT I already set up for crosscompiling for my target (according to http://embedded.von-kannen.net/2014/05/21/qt-4-8-6-on-beaglebone-black/). Now I wanted to use qmake for making the makefile via using `qmake -spec qws/linux-am335-g++ qwt.pro`. That works (I already created the necessary conf-file while compiling qt for arm), but still make uses g++ and not the arm-g++. Why? Can I do something to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did the easy way: Simply pushed all the code I needed on the BeagleBone and compiled everything there. Thus I am able to use QT and qwt now on the BBB without problems.

Answer (score 0):

What is your target distribution? Try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It provides both Qt4 and Qt5 as also Qwt. So you don't need to manually configure and cross-compile.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I gonna try that tomorrow on my target build!

Comment: Is there a way to compile it without having to create a complete new system?

Answer (score 0):

You can cross compile Qwt exactly the way you have tried in your initial posting.

If it doesn't work on your box ( assuming, that there are no Makefiles left from a previous build ) you have to check the mkspec files for "linux-am335-g++", why it references to g++ on your box.